# EOF error when using youtube-dl

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am currently trying to download a youtube video as usual with youtube-dl but keep getting a strange EOF error. When I check my download folder i have the download file split into various parts one with the extension `*.part` another with `*.part-init` then various other files ending in `*.part-SegX` where 'X' is numbered from 0-9.

Here is what terminal output looks like.

```
youtube-dl -c -f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLduVQOagFk
[youtube] wLduVQOagFk: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wLduVQOagFk: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] wLduVQOagFk: Extracting video information
WARNING: unable to extract uploader nickname
[youtube] wLduVQOagFk: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] wLduVQOagFk: Downloading MPD manifest
[dashsegments] Total fragments: 45
[download] Destination: Shonen vs Seinen-wLduVQOagFk.f136.mp4
[download]  35.6% of ~46.96MiB at 30.29KiB/s ETA 16:33ERROR: unable to download video data: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Any ideas on what might be happening and how I can solve this or is this some sort of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @chevallier suggestion I looked into how I could update youtube-dl since `youtube-dl -U` was not working. Here is what worked for me...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Problems are solved by a simple update `youtube-dl -U`.

Comment: Tried to update like you said but got `It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.` output... Can't really remember how I installed it... how can I update in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just download the newest version from here https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html. Should work then. Remember to have python on your system.